# Is there a simple way to get my screen resolution?

Tags: xrandr

I want to find a simple way to find the resolution of every monitor my computer is connected to.

For example, the primary monitor on my laptop is `LVDS-1`. I know the resolution is `1366x768` because of the following command:

```
$ xrandr | grep "LVDS-1"
LVDS-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 277mm x 156mm
```

Presumably, I could use the `--listactivemonitors` option to `xrandr` to retrieve this resolution. The output of this command is:

```
$ xrandr --listactivemonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*LVDS-1 1366/277x768/156+0+0  LVDS-1
```

My questions are:

1. What do the numbers `/277` and `/156` mean in this output?
2. Is there a simple command like `mycommand LVDS-1` that will just return `1366x768`?

Comment: Maybe `xrandr` is not the right tool, here are some good answers: https://askubuntu.com/questions/584688/how-can-i-get-the-monitor-resolution-using-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like with `awk`:

```
xrandr | awk -F'[ +]' '/LVDS-1/ {print $4}'
```